# A Noir detective RPG with published adventure support?

Tags: game-recommendation

I am looking for a noir style detective game for a small group of players, preferably a 1–2 person party (e.g., the detective and the femme fatale or possibly 2 detectives.)

I want to capture the mood of movies like *The Maltese Falcon*, *Out of the Past* and *The Big Sleep*.

I would prefer an easy rules system that's quick to teach new RPG players.

And bonus points if there is a well defined campaign setting or adventure books to go along with it, however those elements are not necessary.

As asked, here are a few more criteria I would like: Preferably the setting is a 1940s/50s style city full of mobsters, crooked cops, racketeers, pimps and other various low lifes for the detectives to investigate. And would prefer to not have to adapt the setting from a different genre such as "Space Noir"; and please **no magic**, I want this to be a fairly realistic and true-to-genre system.

I would prefer a Dice+mod system as I feel its easier for new players to grasp the concept of "Roll that die and add that number" than calculating dice pools.

Theater of the mind is my preferred style of gaming these days as I am short on funds and time to buy/make maps and minis.

I would like the game session to last the standard 3-4 hours and for the campaign to last for at least 5 sessions or so and focus on 1 case for the detective(s). If the system has more than 1 published adventure for multiple cases that would be ideal so I have some choice as to what kind of case they need to solve.

I am also looking for there to be minimal "leveling up" at most I would accept a system that increases health and possibly accuracy of weapons. But even that is debatable.  (in real life we don't increases the "damage" of a bullet the better we get at shooting; just our accuracy. so having things like body armor and stats that reflect things like accuracy and dexterity would be acceptable. but not the "spell damage increases" you get in games like D&D)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, Noir is as much about what is revealed about the characters and the damage done along the way to solving the case as it is about the case itself. For example, in *The Maltese Falcon* Sam's crucial choice of whether to turn in O'Shaughnessy is complicated by the fact that he slept with her. And for many people, the revalation of incest in *Chinatown* is what makes it a taut thriller, not the plot about irrigation.

Then you say you want light rules, no maps, and little to no character advancement.

Which to my mind suggests you may be more interested in the drama of the case than in the plot and investigation. If that is true, then I recommend the oddly-titled [*Hillfolk*](http://www.pelgranepress.com/?cat=222). The game is named after the first setting devised for it, iron-age raiders in the Levant.

But what you want is the game engine it's based on: DramaSystem, devised by Robin Laws to put the interactions between characters firmly in the spotlight in an RPG. Essentially, Hillfolk is designed to produce sessions that work like modern TV dramas.

The book contains 29 additional settings or, "series pitches", that you can use as examples or mine for material. Putting together a series for Hillfolk is very simple - you've done most of the work required in your question.

So your duo could spend several sessions working a single case, as in *True Detective*, and that would comprise a "season". You can have all the Noir you want without space, mutants, magic, or anything else, just by declaring it to be so.

The details are worked out collaboratively, in play. As a GM, all you need is an initial situation and some ideas of how to put pressure on the characters. This should help make up for the lack of published adventures. In fact, none of the settings for Hillfolk include adventures. It just doesn't work that way. Plot emerges from the characters following their own goals and responding to the pressures you introduce.

Mystery in RPGs presents a unique set of problems. For further understanding of the topic, I point you towards the excellent GURPS Mysteries book, as well as the entire GUMSHOE system, also by Robin Laws, devoted to investigative gaming.

Comment: Character advancement can happen in more ways than just increasing your stats. Having the characters grow and evolve in their personality is one thing that will be happening, just like in a Noir film. Not sure if that changes the suggestions you made. If not, cool; I just wanted to clear up what may have been a misinterpretation of the minimal leveling up thing.

Comment: @MC_Hambone - in Hillfolk, characters change. But they don't really advance, except in as much as they move from one set of conflicts and on to another.